# mxe cross compiling linux to windows vtk example

Tags: linux, windows, vtk, cross-compiling, mxe

I would like to know if there is an example out there, or could somebody post one, for compiling a vtk .exe app using [MXE](http://mxe.cc/). The headers and libraries are built but I can't seem to get it to work. I have managed to get Qt working. I usually use my own makefiles and am not as familiar with cmake, qmake, etc. I need an example to show me how to make this stuff work. A working example showing the includes and links required to build a basic functioning vtk.exe application from mxe built libs and headers.

I have tried:

```
export PATH=/home/.../mxe/usr/bin:$PATH 
i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -Wall -g -Wno-deprecated -I/home/.../include/vtk-5.8 -c app.cpp 
i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -o appWindows app.o -L/home/.../lib/vtk/5.8 -lvtkRendering -lvtkGraphics -lvtkCommon -lvtkFiltering -l.. -l... etc.
```

I have also tried:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/.../mxe/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/share/cmake/mxe-conf.cm‌​ake.
```

Getting libvtkRendering errors. This same procedure works with my Linux headers and binaries.

I have also tried the binaries from Point Cloud Library. Also didn't work.

Comment: Error output please? And source code?

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this from a git clone on master for MXE. Read the mailing list for the checksum error fixes. I am currently getting an opengl error during compilation of vtk6. I am not seeing the above error mentioned.

I will post the new error messages later tonight. Please let me know if you are still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Two years later, CMake is more and more THE reference!
Check this latest post [C/C++ Development for Windows Sans Windows](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/877)